# Geocoder: Near method removed from query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-geocoder

Using [Geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) in Rails 4, I'm running to an issue trying to display the distance on a page. I have the models Kid, Dad and Mom. Kid belongs to a Mom and Dad. Mom's are based on an address or being online.

**Dads Controller**

```
def show
  @dad = Dad.find(params[:id])
  near = Mom.near(@user_location, 5000, :select => "kids.*")
  online = Mom.where(is_online: true)    
  near = near.arel.constraints.reduce(:and)
  online = online.arel.constraints.reduce(:and)
  mom = Mom.where((near).or(online))
  @kids = @dad.kids.joins(:mom).merge(mom).order("moms.is_online DESC")
end
```

Now when I try to use `distance` in the view:

```
<% @kids.each do |kid| %>
  <%= kid.mom.distance.round(0) %>
<% end %>
```

I get the error:

```
Undefined method `distance' for #<Mom:0x9e7fc94>
```

After debugging, I found out the `distance` for `Mom` isn't working because the `near` method is gone. I'm not sure what I can do to get it to be apart of the `Mom` model again. I was looking here: [github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/issues/99](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/issues/99) and here: [github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#known-issue](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#known-issue) for some possible answers. Any idea on what I should do?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, maybe it is not the most elegant solution, but what about:

```
<%= kid.mom.distance_to [kid.latitude, kid.longitude] %>
```

Comment: After more debugging I found out the `distance` method isn't on Mom altogether which means the moms aren't ordering by distance either. I'm getting the distance from the Mom based on the users location. So, I did `[current_user.latitude, current_user.longitude]` and this does show the distance but this wouldn't be needed if I can get my `distance` back in my query. Any ideas? I was looking here: https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/issues/99 and here: https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#known-issue